# Server not working for multiple clients

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

Please tell me what is the problem with my server code. It is not working for the two clients simultaneously. It is running only for the client that I run first. I am new to python and socket programming. Kindly help me out here.

```
import socket
import sys
import thread
import time
# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 10001)
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
sock.bind(server_address)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % sock.getsockname()
sock.listen(1)
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
def my(threadName , delay):

    while True:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'

        try:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'client connected:', client_address
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(16)
                print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
                a=['a' ,'e', 'i' , 'o' , 'u']
                for i in data:
                    if i in a:
                        data = data.replace(i, '')

                        data=data.upper()
                        print data


                print'\nUpper case string:'

                if data:
                    connection.sendall(data)
                else:
                    break
        finally:
            connection.close()


thread.start_new_thread(my , ("Thread-1" , 8,))
thread.start_new_thread(my , ("Thread-2" , 10,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **socketServer** module it easy to use for multiple clients
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socketserver.html

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is calling

```
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
```

only once, thus accepting only a single connection, and then proceeding to run 2 threads that use the same global connection.

Instead a server should accept new connections in a loop and launch new handlers as connections are accepted:

```
from itertools import count
from threading import Thread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 10001)
    data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
    sock.bind(server_address)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % sock.getsockname()
    sock.listen(1)

    for i in count(1):
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
        # Blocked here until a new connection is accepted
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        name = "Thread-%d" % i
        t = Thread(target=my,
                   args=(name, 8, connection, client_address),
                   name=name)
        t.start()
```

I took the liberty of changing your low level thread API usage with the [higher-level threading interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

The handler function should receive the connection as an argument instead of using a global variable, as the connection is unique to that handler.

```
from contextlib import closing

def my(threadName, delay, connection, client_address):
    print >>sys.stderr, 'client connected:', client_address
    with closing(connection):
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received %r' % data
            a = {'a' ,'e', 'i' , 'o' , 'u'}
            for i in data:
                if i in a:
                    data = data.replace(i, '')

            data = data.upper()    
            print 'Upper case string:', data

            if data:
                connection.sendall(data)

            else:
                break
```